# Split arrays and loop through to post to web hook endpoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, split, zapier

I am trying to take some data from equal length CSV strings and split into arrays, then sequentially loop through these arrays to post individual lines to JSON through Zapier.

Here is my current code - for ease of my understanding, I have input simplified CSV strings as the first 3 lines:

```js
var inputDataworkorders = "a,b,c,d,e,f"
var inputDatalats = "g,h,i,j,k,l"
var inputDatalongs = "m,n,o,p,q,r"

var workorder = inputDataworkorders.split(',')
var lat = inputDatalats.split(',')
var long = inputDatalongs.split(',')
var otherUrl = 'https://webpage.com/catch/13579/'


for (var i = 0; i <= workorder.length; i++) {
  var payload = {
    workorder: [workorder[i]],
    lat: [lat[i]],
    long: [long[i]],
  };
}

fetch(otherUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }, callback)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    callback(null, json);
    console.log(json)
  });
```

What I am wanting is something like this for the first loop:

```js
{workorder: "b",
lat: "h",
long: "n"}
```

And this for the second loop, and so on:

```js
{workorder: "a",
lat: "g",
long: "m"}
```

I have read every possible help article I could find on this and have also tried to get some help via Freelancer, but to no avail. It doesn't seem like an advanced concept to me, but this is beyond my basic understanding. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You wan to call `fetch` for every value of payload, right? If so, you should call it inside the for-loop. Also, change `i <= workorder.length` to `i < workorder.length` as the `i = workorder.length`, index doesn't exist on the defined arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three  issues:

1. You need an array containing each `payload` created in the loop. Otherwise `payload` that you send with `fetch()` will only be the  very last object created in the `for()` loop
2. Get rid of the `[]` wrapping the values for each property in the object
3. Your loop iteration must be less than array length not `<=` since length is a count that starts at 1 but array indexing starts at zero. If you do `<=` the last iteration over shoots the length of the array

```js
var inputDataworkorders = "a,b,c,d,e,f"
var inputDatalats = "g,h,i,j,k,l"
var inputDatalongs = "m,n,o,p,q,r"

var workorder = inputDataworkorders.split(',')
console.log(workorder)
var lat = inputDatalats.split(',')
var long = inputDatalongs.split(',')
var otherUrl = 'https://webpage.com/catch/13579/'

// array to store all `payload` objects
var results =[];

for (var i = 0; i < workorder.length; i++) {
  var payload = {
    workorder: workorder[i],
    lat: lat[i],
    long: long[i],
  };
  
  results.push(payload)
}

console.log(results)
// now send `results` array to server
```

Answer (score 0):

In your payload variable, you are passing each property as an array. To get the desired output, simply change that to:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= workorder.length; i++) {
    var payload = {
        workorder: workorder[i],
        lat: lat[i],
        long: long[i]
    };
}
```

You'll need to Call fetch inside the for loop or store the payload in an array and push to it.

Also don't forget to change the loop to only **<** instead of **<=** as i = 0 and the last result would be undefined.